# Change the string from database column while I displays over html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is how i am set my page according my database column:

[image]

This is the code (only for the first column)

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th style="font-size: 20px">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fileName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 15px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fileName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("File Details", "Details", new { id = item.id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

How can i change `fileName` to another string when over my html page ?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't comprehend this statement: **How can i change fileName to another string when go over my database and ahow my object on my page ?**

Comment: Instead of fileName i want to change this string (only over the web) to something else

Comment: how do you want it to look? should it be set to something random? should it be set to something the user wants to update/add?

Comment: Instead of fileName which is my database column i want to become just File Name:

Comment: Test out what I just posted. Maybe it will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work(I am unable to test it at the moment, not on windows),

```
[Display(Name = "File Name")]    //this is the line you must add.
public string fileName{get;set;} //this is your model property name.
```

This should change it to `File Name`

Comment: Where i need to change it ? inside my class or inside my Index.cshtml ?

Comment: inside your model class. @user1860934